# problem with jquery's "live" function

Tags: javascript, jquery

### the problem

this works fine:

```
$('#edit_curriculum .generated').children().blur(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

but this doesn't:

```
$('#edit_curriculum .generated').children().live('blur', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

**obs:** the functions are wrapped in a `$(document).ready` event.

---

### the outputs

working:

```
<input type=​"text" name=​"phones[]​" class=​"medium phone valid">
```

not working:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
k.errorjquery.js:17
k.filterjquery.js:17
kjquery.js:17
c.querySelectorAll.kjquery.js:17
k.matchesSelectorjquery.js:17
f.extend.filterjquery.js:17
f.fn.extend.isjquery.js:17
f.fn.extend.closestjquery.js:17
Njquery.js:16
f.event.handlejquery.js:17
f.event.add.k.i.handle.kjquery.js:16
f.event.triggerjquery.js:17
ejquery.js:17
```

Comment: version of jQuery, example of HTML code (possibly link)? there is no error in the posted code

Comment: acually it does, as pointed by ghayes in his answer :p

Comment: My bad. +1 for the question and the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current **selector**, now and in the future.

This function is meant to work on a `selector`, not a collection of elements.  I would use the following syntax:

```
 $('#edit_curriculum .generated > *').live('blur', function(){
   console.log(this);
 });
```

This selector will get any immediate children (hence what you had before) but with `selection` and not `traversal`.  This should allow you to use `live()` as you would expect.  Hope this helps!

Comment: well, it indeed works! thank you. but what if i need some traversing before the live? what should i do to make more complex selections?

Comment: oh, i finally understood it. Obviously I can't do traversing in elements that doesn't exist. haha - i guess i'll just check the docs for more complex selectors. again, thank you (:

Comment: FYI, I just found the pertaining quote from the docs: `DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above`